# How to include bold+italic font in an equation

Tags: fonts, equations, amsmath

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{R}_I(\mathbf{u}_{e}) = \int\limits_{\Omega_e}{B_{LI}^{T}} \mathbf S_{e}d\Omega
\label{eq:one}

\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

I want the letter R and u on the left side of the equation to be bold+Italic. I have tried writing `\textit{}`before `\mathbf` and after it but still I don't get the desired output.

Comment: `\bm{R}` from `bm` package

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks. That worked perfectly!

Comment: If you use mathtools you can use ´\boldsymbol´ without an additional package

Comment: @MaxNoe `\boldsymbol` comes from `amsbsy` package (included into `mathtools` via `amsmath`. The amsmath documentation documents this as: `amsbsy For backward compatibility this package continues to exist but use of  the newer bm package that comes with LaTeX is recommended instead.`  Note that  "newer" here means 1996:-)

Comment: Haha, ok thanks for the clarification ;) I'm using unicode-math in nearly all my documents.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `\bm{R}` from the `bm` package.